# Import cmake project from github in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to import the project [grive2](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2.git) into eclipse. I figured the easiest way would be to use Eclipses' build in git support. 
This was performed with File->Import->Git->Projects From GIT
Then I choose `Clone URI` and entered the URI. After setting the destination path I was shown this dialog:

[image]

For which I selected the `Import using the New Project wizard` option (I don't know if that's correct!?
Then in the new wizard I select the Makefile project with existing code.

[image]

In the next window I had to set the path of the project and the compiler:

[image]

After this step the project was entered in the eclipse tree of the projects on the right. 
When now clicking the build (little hammer in the bar) I receive the output message

```
 18:55:32 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project    
 grive2 ****
 make all 
 make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.

 18:55:32 Build Finished (took 73ms)
```

What else do I need to do to get it to build and compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their git repository, the readme has the following instruction:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```

You need to run cmake first. It it will do what it needs to do and gives you a make file to run. You don't need eclipse to build and compile!

Comment: I don't just wanna build it, but also modify the code. But following the above steps gave me the Makefile and Eclipse recognized it. It works fine now, Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The eclipse marketplace has a plugin that can generate the makefiles and build directory for you: `cmake4eclipse`